# show form input box if link clicked

Tags: jquery, this

I have comment form for every posts. I would like to show the input box only if the comment link is clicked.

```
$("*#comment_form").hide();
$(".comment_link").click (function(){
  $("#comment_form").show(); // problem here...
});
```

I have used this script above to hide all comment boxes ( comment div) on page load. and when the comment link is clicked, i want to show one comment box for that particular post.

```
<a class="comment_link href="#">Comment</a>
<div id="comment_form">
<form id="form_comment" action="docomment.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="comment">
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: is it your HTML markup? if so you are missing an " on your div with id of comment_form and your coment_link class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

works perfect if you just fix your HTML markup: http://jsfiddle.net/voigtan/QAvKT/

added a css class instead if you are using more form elemens in your document at once: http://jsfiddle.net/voigtan/QAvKT/3/ (added a preventDefault on your a-elements)

Comment: when the link is clicked, it displays all the forms with id #comment_form. I only want to display the form for particular post.

Comment: you do know that an id is unique on a page? so your markup is invalid.

Comment: change your markup and target it with your new markup, an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/voigtan/QAvKT/3/

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `"` here `<div id="comment_form>`